# Quasar - Cordova Build for Android

Tags: android, macos, cordova, gradle, quasar

I'm trying to export my quasar app for Android via cordova:
I ran into several issues an error which get to fix step by step. (Lots of mismatching Java and Android Versions.
Now I get this error with Gradle which I can't read anymore.

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/jannofleischer/Library/Android/sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jannofleischer/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /Users/jannofleischer/Library/Android/sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/03 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Warning: unerwartetes Element (URI:"", lokal:"base-extension"). Erwartete Elemente sind <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 572ms
48 actionable tasks: 48 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s): 
    /Users/jannofleischer/rubbellose/src-cordova/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/jannofleischer/Library/Android/sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/jannofleischer/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: /Users/jannofleischer/Library/Android/sdk
Command failed with exit code 1: apkanalyzer manifest target-sdk /Users/jannofleischer/rubbellose/src-cordova/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli.getAaptInvokerFromSdk(ApkAnalyzerCli.java:277)
    at com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli.main(ApkAnalyzerCli.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more

 App • Command "cordova" failed with exit code: 1
 App • Updated Cordova config.xml

 App • ⚠️   FAIL  Cordova CLI has failed
```

Anyone has a hint what's causing this error or how I can make use of the --warning-mode all option?

Operating System is MacOS by the way (M1 ARM Chip, if that matters)

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem and finally fixed for me. u can change version of the Gradle and JDK from project structure (using Android Studio / File Menu) [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-java-sdk-path-in-android-studio/amp/) can be help.

**So for resolve the problem u can use this tutorial, note that Gradle version must be compatible with jdk version.**

---

**Links**

Gradle Release Notes:
https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/release-notes.html

Java and Gradle Compatibility Matrix: [docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java)

---

**Compatibility Example**

Java (JDK): jdk-18.0.2.1

Gradle: 7.5

Embedded Kotlin version: 1.6.21

Kotlin Language version: 1.4

---

**Enviroments**

Windows:

- setx ANDROID_HOME "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
- setx ANDROID_SDK_ROOT "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
- setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1"
- setx path "%path%;%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools;%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools;"

Unix (macOS, linux):

- export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
- export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$HOME/Android/Sdk"
- export JAVA_HOME="{{path to java}}/jdk-18.0.2.1"
- export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools;
- PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools

---

**cordova requirements**

Requirements check results for android:

Java JDK: installed 18.0.2

Android SDK: installed true

Android target: installed android-32,android-31,android-30,android-29,android-28,android-27,android-26,android-25,android-24,Google Inc.:Google APIs:24,android-17,android-15,android-7

Gradle: installed C:\Users#myuserprofile#\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\gradle-7.5\bin\gradle.BAT

---

After Build (Result):

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 19s
52 actionable tasks: 52 executed