# Build error when running cordova project on quasar

Tags: cordova, android-gradle-plugin, quasar

I am trying to do "quasar build -m android" according to documentation https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-cordova-apps/build-commands#building-for-production
I followed the preparation instructions https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-cordova-apps/preparation, all system variables are specified and paths are specified
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPKt2.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRegi.png

The documentation states that Gradle version 4.10.3 is required, the Java download link suggests installing version 8. Under these conditions, if I execute "cordova requirements" from the project's "src-cordova" folder, then I get no errors

```
PS C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\lmschat-mobile\src-cordova> cordova requirements                      

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-34,android-UpsideDownCakePrivacySandbox,android-TiramisuPrivacySandbox,android-33,android-28,android-27,android-26
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Gradle\gradle-4.10.3\bin\gradle.BAT
```

But when doing a build via "cordova build --release --warning-mode=all" I get the following errors

```
PS C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\lmschat-mobile\src-cordova> cordova build --release --warning-mode=all
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Maksim\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Maksim\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Maksim\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'lmschat.1t'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\lmschat-mobile\src-cordova\platforms\android\gradlew -b C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\lmschat-mobile\src-cordova\platforms\android\build.gradle :app:bundleRelease
```

Then I upgrade the Java version to 11 for compatibility (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html), change the system variable path, but when doing "cordova requirements" I get this:

```
PS C:\Users\Maksim\Desktop\lmschat-mobile\src-cordova> cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 11.0.18
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 5 more
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Gradle\gradle-4.10.3\bin\gradle.BAT
Some of requirements check failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

After running "cordova build --release --warning-mode=all" an APK file should be generated. It's not happening now

Comment: You can use this help:
[Refference from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75265586/20925263)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using Capacitor (quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-capacitor-apps/…) and without changing the configuration files, I was able to build without errors

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using linux and had the exact same issue, after scratching my head and reading a lot of post about it with no solution whatsoever, realized this.

I was using the JAVA_HOME path pointing to openjdk-8-jre on the OS. but Android Studio by default uses it's own JAVA_HOME path.

In my case I unzipped the installer in /opt, so the path to the Android Studio folder is /opt/android-studio and by default (as mentioned before), Android Studio points (in my case), to /opt/android-studio/jbr. So for me changing the value of JAVA_HOME to the mentioned path fixed the issue.

After running the command this would take care of Gradle and everything else, even removed openjdk from system and it works as it should be.

I believe this change should work on windows too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution didn't help me. I tried using Capacitor (https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-capacitor-apps/build-commands) and without changing the configuration files, I was able to build without errors